# Group a list of N elements into sub-groups of two or one

Tags: python, combinations

I have a list of n numbers, e.g. [1, 2, 3, 4] and I want to write some code in python which finds all possible combinations where the numbers are grouped into either 2s or 1s and all n elements are present.

For example with the n=4 case the solution will be,

```
[(0, 1, 2, 3), ((0, 1), 2, 3), ((0, 2), 1, 3), ((0, 3), 2, 1),
 ((1, 2), 0, 3), ((1, 3), 0, 2), ((2, 3), 0, 1), ((0, 1), (2, 3)),
 ((0, 2), (1, 3)), ((0, 3), (1, 2))]
```

To give an intuitive explanation, I am looking for all combinations of four people where they are either in a pair or working alone.

I have tried the following mixture of combinations but I cannot see a clear method of continuing from here,

```
pairs = list(combinations([0, 1, 2, 3], 2))
groups = list(combinations(pairs, 2))

unique = []
for p in groups:
    if len(set([i for sub in p for i in sub])) == 4:
        unique.append(p)

unique + pairs
>> [((0, 1), (2, 3)),
    ((0, 2), (1, 3)),
    ((0, 3), (1, 2)),
    (0, 1),
    (0, 2),
    (0, 3),
    (1, 2),
    (1, 3),
    (2, 3)]
```

If I could fill in each entry so that all four numbers were present by inserting them as individuals (not in pairs) this would give my solution.

I don't need to do this for very large lists so I am not overly concerned with running time (I say this as I am aware that my current method can get out of hand quickly with large n).

Any help would be great!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was interestingly tricky. I used the `combinations` function to pull out each even subset and then wrote a recursive pairing process to make all possible pairings in those even subsets.

```py
from itertools import combinations

def make_pairs(source, pairs=None, used=None):
    if pairs is None: # entry level
        sin = 0
        results = []
        pairs = []
        used = [False] * len(source)
    else:
        sin = 1
        while used[sin]:
            sin +=1
    used[sin] = True
    for dex in range(sin + 1, len(source)):
        if not used[dex]:
            pairs.append( (source[sin], source[dex]))
            if len(pairs)*2 == len(source):
                yield tuple(pairs)
            else:
                used[dex] = True
                yield from make_pairs(source, pairs, used)
                used[dex] = False
            pairs.pop()
    used[sin]=False


def make_ones_and_twos(source):
    yield tuple(source) # all singles case
    inpair = 2
    while inpair <= len(source):
        for paired in combinations(source,inpair): # choose elements going in pairs
            singles = tuple(sorted(set(source)-set(paired))) # others are singleton
            # partition paired into actual pairs
            for pairing in make_pairs(paired):
                yield (pairing+singles)
        inpair += 2

# sample run       
elements = ['a','c','g','t','u']

print(*make_ones_and_twos(elements),sep='\n')
```

giving output

```
('a', 'c', 'g', 't', 'u')
(('a', 'c'), 'g', 't', 'u')
(('a', 'g'), 'c', 't', 'u')
(('a', 't'), 'c', 'g', 'u')
(('a', 'u'), 'c', 'g', 't')
(('c', 'g'), 'a', 't', 'u')
(('c', 't'), 'a', 'g', 'u')
(('c', 'u'), 'a', 'g', 't')
(('g', 't'), 'a', 'c', 'u')
(('g', 'u'), 'a', 'c', 't')
(('t', 'u'), 'a', 'c', 'g')
(('a', 'c'), ('g', 't'), 'u')
(('a', 'g'), ('c', 't'), 'u')
(('a', 't'), ('c', 'g'), 'u')
(('a', 'c'), ('g', 'u'), 't')
(('a', 'g'), ('c', 'u'), 't')
(('a', 'u'), ('c', 'g'), 't')
(('a', 'c'), ('t', 'u'), 'g')
(('a', 't'), ('c', 'u'), 'g')
(('a', 'u'), ('c', 't'), 'g')
(('a', 'g'), ('t', 'u'), 'c')
(('a', 't'), ('g', 'u'), 'c')
(('a', 'u'), ('g', 't'), 'c')
(('c', 'g'), ('t', 'u'), 'a')
(('c', 't'), ('g', 'u'), 'a')
(('c', 'u'), ('g', 't'), 'a')
```

Comment: I know comments aren't meant for just praise, but this is a beautiful solution. Thanks!

Comment: I had pretty much converged on this exact solution, when I saw yours, so I can happily move on now. Good one by the way (praising both of us :p).

Comment: The number of solutions is given by [OEIS A000085](https://oeis.org/A000085). Happily my routine matches this.

Answer (score 1):

This may do it:

```py
from itertools import combinations

elements = [0, 1, 2, 3]

pairs = list(combinations(elements, 2))
groups = list(combinations(pairs, 2))

unique = []
for p in groups:
    if len(set([i for sub in p for i in sub])) == 4:
        unique.append(p)

pairs_with_singles = []
for pair in pairs:
    missing = set(elements) - set(pair)
    pairs_with_singles.append((pair, *missing))

print(unique + pairs_with_singles + [tuple(elements)])
```

Comment: Hello, thanks but this only works for n = 4. Sorry if my question was not clear but I want to do the same thing for any n.  Do you see a way you could tweak your answer to work for any N? I appreciate the quick response!